# jQuery form is properly submitted only if an alert is added in the executable code

Tags: jquery, regex, alert, form-submit

I'm trying to search for a word in an html file when the submit button is clicked (as far as  I know my regexp is ok; it works). The problem is my code runs only if I add an alert at the bottom of the code (not anywhere else). What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ana").submit(function () {
            var lemma = $("#lexi").val();

            var lex = new RegExp(".*<b>" + lemma + ".*");

            jQuery.get('alfa.html', function (data) {
                $("#apo").html(data.match(lex));
            });

            alert(lemma);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="apo"></div>
```

Comment: The code you provide works submits the form fine for me without the alert. Are you getting any errors in your console? Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I am confused - is #ana a form or a button?

Comment: Do you want the form to submit, as you suggest in your title? Or do you only want to execute the jQuery get function? Doesn't make sense to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but my assumption is that you need to prevent default on the submit function. Something like this:

```
$("#ana").on( 'submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // the rest of your code
});
```

Here's my reasoning: since you're not telling the page not to do its default form action on submit, your get request, which is asynchronous, isn't getting time to do its thing before the page finishes its action. alerts, however, pause page actions which is why it's working when you add in the alert at the end there.

Comment: @nikolas I'm glad I could help! Since it worked for you, could you accept my answer?